# Nullpointer in simple grails controller unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I need a little assistance with a strange issue I am facing unit testing a very basic Grails 2.4.1 controller.

Given this controller:

```
class AuthenticationEventController {
    def index() {
        // Sorry, ajax only!
        if(!request.xhr) {
            redirect(controller: "main")
            return false
        }

        render(template: "index")
        return
    }
}
```

And this test:

```
@TestFor(AuthenticationEventController)
class AuthenticationEventControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "Test that the index rejects non-ajax calls"() {
        given:
            request.isXhr = { false }

        when:
            controller.index()

        then:
            response.redirectedUrl == '/main'
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException on the "controller.index()" call.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)
    at au.com.intrinsicminds.advansys.controller.AuthenticationEventControllerSpec.Test that the index rejects non-ajax calls(AuthenticationEventControllerSpec.groovy:17)
```

Comment: Your test passes in grails 2.3.8 (I don't have 2.4.1 yet), so perhaps its a grails caching thing - perhaps trying grails clean if you haven't already? Otherwise it might be worth looking what changed in Grails 2.4

Comment: To get this to work in 2.4.1, i had to add an empty def setup(){} and def cleanup() {} method to the test otherwise i got method not found errors, maybe that's worth a try for you?

Comment: 2.4.0 and 2.4.1 both had some serious issues that are resolved in 2.4.2. I didn't have a chance to try your test but I'd consider moving to 2.4.2 if possible.

Comment: You should not need an empty `setup()` or `cleanup()` method and you shouldn't have to upgrade to 2.4.2 to test this.  The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/xhrtest contains the code I pasted into an answer below and that test appears to work.

Answer (score 26):

the problem most likely is you are using

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
```

instead of

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

for `@Transactional` annotation in the groovy class.

why, no clear answer as to the major difference or why the test doesn't do well with this.
Also this usually only happens if you are testing a class with 2 more class layers behind it.

Comment: In my case, I was using grails.transaction.Transactional in a spring bean from grails/src. I switched it to use spring's @Transactional and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I had this issue in a test as well, but my problem was that I was using grails.transaction.Transactional without getting the object from the spring context.  I was just creating the object for the test as I didn't need the dependencies for the section I was testing.  Using the spring annotation would work at test time, but not at runtime, and the inverse would occur for the grails annotation.  I had to go back to the test and allow the spring context to inject the object I was testing.

Comment: This fix also works for me. After I found NPE in meta-programming with invokeMethod. Without NPE everything works well with grails.transaction.Transactional

Answer (score 4):

Do you use a domain class anywhere else in your code? I had the same problem (NPE raised by TransactionTemplate#execute) and the solution was to use @Mock to one of my entities, as per this jira issue: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11045

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with Grails 2.4.1.

A controller:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/AuthenticationEventController.groovy
package demo

class AuthenticationEventController {
    def index() {
        if(!request.xhr) {
            redirect(controller: "main")
        } else {
            render(template: "index")
        }
    }
}
```

A unit test:

```
// test/unit/demo/AuthenticationEventControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(AuthenticationEventController)
class AuthenticationEventControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "Test that the index redirects for non-ajax calls"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.redirectedUrl == '/main'
    }

    void "Test that index renders template for ajax calls"() {
        given:
        request.makeAjaxRequest()
        views['/authenticationEvent/_index.gsp'] = 'my template text'

        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.contentAsString == 'my template text'
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got same stacktrace when tried to Spy Transactional service.

I found solution that helps me. So I just init transactionManager in spied service.

See example:

```
SomeTransactionalService sts = Spy(SomeTransactionalService)
sts.transactionManager = transactionManager // so you need to add  init transactionManager
```